# document.creatElement("li") does not go to next line

Tags: javascript, html

New to programming here. I am trying to display the customer's information on a page.

index.html

```
<HTML><script src="javascript.js"></script>
<body>
<ul id="cus_list"></ul>
</body></html>
```

javascript.js

```
var customers = [{
  company: "company1"
  name: "name1"
  phone: "1234567"
  image: "img/img1.jpg"
  url: "www.url.com"
}];


var item = customers[0],
  list = document.getElementById('cus_list'),
  fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
  element = document.createElement("li");

element.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Company: " + item.company));
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Name: " + item.name + " "));

fragment.appendChild(element);
list.appendChild(fragment);
```

This is the result:

• Company: company1Name: name1

Why wouldn't the name go on the next line?

Comment: You JSON is not in a valid format. Add commas.

Answer (score 1):

> You are creating only one `li` element. To get elements as a list, you must have `n` number of `li` elements to have `n` number of lines.

Try this:

```js
var customers = [{
  company: "company1",
  name: "name1",
  phone: "1234567",
  image: "img/img1.jpg",
  url: "www.url.com"
}];


var item = customers[0],
  list = document.getElementById('cus_list'),
  fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
  element1 = document.createElement("li"),
  element2 = document.createElement("li");

element1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Company: " + item.company));
element2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Name: " + item.name + " "));

fragment.appendChild(element1);
fragment.appendChild(element2);
list.appendChild(fragment);
```

```html
<ul id="cus_list"></ul>
```

Or even a simplified way to do so:

```js
var customers = [{
  company: "company1",
  name: "name1",
  phone: "1234567",
  image: "img/img1.jpg",
  url: "www.url.com"
}];
var item = customers[0],
  list = document.getElementById('cus_list'),
  element1 = document.createElement("li"),
  element2 = document.createElement("li");
element1.innerText = "Company: " + item.company;
element2.innerText = "Name: " + item.name + " ";
list.appendChild(element1);
list.appendChild(element2);
```

```html
<ul id="cus_list"></ul>
```

**Also note that you had invalid object. Every `key-value` should be separated by `,`**

Comment: Additionally, I would recommend a definition list with terms and descriptions instead of an unordered list.

Comment: @Oriol, Any reason to do so ?

Comment: It's just that `<dl><dt>Company</dt><dd>company1</dd></dl>` seems more semantic than `<ul><li>Company: company1</li></ul>`

Answer (score 0):

Simplified

```js
 
var customers = [{
  company: "company1",
  name: "name1",
  phone: "1234567",
  image: "img/img1.jpg",
  url: "www.url.com"
}];

var item = customers[0],
  list = document.getElementById('cus_list'),
  element1 = document.createElement("li"),
  element2 = document.createElement("li"),
  element3 = document.createElement("li"),
  element4 = document.createElement("li"),
  element5 = document.createElement("li");
element1.innerText = "Company: " + item.company;
element2.innerText = "Name: " + item.name + " ";
element3.innerText = "Phone: " + item.phone + " ";
element4.innerText = "image: " + item.image + " ";
element5.innerText = "url: " + item.url + " ";
list.appendChild(element1);
list.appendChild(element2);
list.appendChild(element3);
list.appendChild(element4);
list.appendChild(element5);
```

```html
<ul id="cus_list"></ul>
```

You miss to add **,** in your customers array object

```
var customers = [{
      company: "company1",
      name: "name1",
      phone: "1234567",
      image: "img/img1.jpg",
      url: "www.url.com"
    }];
```

Comment: That does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jquery, something like below code

```
var li = $('<li></li>');
li.html('Test!');
$('#cus_list').append(li);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create li tag for each your data attribute
try this.

```
var customers = [{
  company: "company1",
  name: "name1",
  phone: "1234567",
  image: "img/img1.jpg",
  url: "www.url.com"
}];

var renderElement = function(ele_text){
    var element = document.createElement("li");
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ele_text));
    return element;
}

customers.forEach(function(customer) {
    var list = document.getElementById('cus_list'),
    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    fragment.appendChild(renderElement("Company: " + customer.company));
    fragment.appendChild(renderElement("Name: " + customer.name));
    list.appendChild(fragment);
});
```